# Discord.js embeds: TypeError: Discord.MessageEmbed is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js, typeerror

I was recently trying to add a MessageEmbed for my discord bot, but I get this error:

> TypeError: Discord.MessageEmbed is not a constructor

I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this, I have tried some of the rips I could find online, some include trying to re-install node.js and discord.js, other mention a different method like using NewMessageEmbed() instead, but none of them have been working for me, it would be great someone with a bit more experience than me could provide a solution, I have provided all the code involved and screenshot of the error, thanks in advance.

Command file:

```js
    module.exports = {
    name: 'command',
    description: "Embeds!",
    execute(message, args, Discord){
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FFA62B')
        .setTitle('Rules')
        .setURL('https://discord.gg/fPAsvEey2k')
        .setDescription('**This is an embed for the server rules.**')
        .addFields(
            {name: '1.', value: 'Treat everyone with respect. Absolutely no harassment, witch hunting, sexism, racism or hate speech will be tolerated.'},
            {name: '2.', value: 'No spam or self-promotion (server invites, advertisements, etc.) without permission from a staff member. This includes DMing fellow members.'},
            {name: '3.', value: 'No NSFW or obscene content. This includes text, images or links featuring nudity, sex, hard violence or other graphically disturbing content.'},
            {name: '4.', value: 'if you see something against the rules or something that makes you feel unsafe, let staff know. We want this server to be a welcoming space!'},
            {name: '5.', value: 'Keep public conversations in English.'},
            {name: '6.', value: 'This list is not exhaustive and will be updated as we see fit.'}


        )
        .setImage('./images/rules.png')
        .setFooter('Make sure to follow the rules');

        message.channel.send(newEmbed);
    }

}
```

Main file:

```js
// grabs the discord.js bot file for import //
const {Client, Intents, Collection} = require('discord.js');

// create the client for the bot //
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

// prefix to use for bot commands //
const prefix = '!';

const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('./commands/discord');

client.commands = new Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


// log to console that the bot has successfully logged in //
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("Reformed Esports is online");
});

/* Command handler, checking if message starts with prefix and is not the bot,
 allowing commands to have multiple words */
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if(command === 'discord'){
        client.commands.get('discord').execute(message, args);
    } else if(command === 'pugs') {
        client.commands.get('pugs').execute(message, args);
    } else if(command === 'command'){
        client.commands.get('command').execute(message, args, Discord)
    }
});

// bot login using discord bot token //
client.login('blank');
```

Image of full error:
[image: Error code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing the discord.js module but instead you pass a file. This may have different functions, properties, etc than the discord.js module.

This code will fix the error:

```js
client.commands.get('command').execute(message, args, require('discord.js'))
```

Additionally, embeds must now be sent using the `embeds` property

```js
message.channel.send({ embeds: [newEmbed] })
```

Comment: It seems to have fixed the main error, but i get an error saying that the discord api cant send an empty message:

https://pastebin.com/E14gcT5m

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sending `./commands/discord` as an argument instead of the real discord.js package. I would add `Embed` to the `const {Client, Intents, Collection} = require('discord.js');`, and send `Embed` instead of `Discord` inside of `client.commands.get('command').execute(message, args, Discord)`.